# Completed 500 Internal Server Error in Rails 4 Devise Signup process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

When I go to signup a new user on the site I fill in the form, click submit, and it sits there for a few seconds, then dispays 'We're sorry, but something went wrong.'

The Log is below...

https://gist.github.com/th3cuda/225f1352a7cfeee3f8f8

This is deployed on digitalocean.

production.rb

```
# Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'MY_HOST' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.MY_DOMAIN.com',
  :port                 => 465,
  :domain               => 'MY_DOMAIN',
  :user_name            => 'MY_EMAIL',
  :password             => 'PASSWORD',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
end
```

Comment: Did you setup the Action Mailer settings?

Comment: On the server? How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I have the mailer set up in production.rb if that's what you mean

Comment: any idea what's causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's taking a while, it could be looking for sendmail (it uses /usr/sbin/sendmail by default) to send the email.

I would make sure that it's in place, that it can be used by the app, and that the config/(Dev, Prod, etc.) allows it to deliver email.

Is any of that helpful?  Let me know what you find so I can give a better answer.

Comment: So I need to change that to actionmailer?

Comment: Only if you're generating and sending your own emails, in this case Devise is sending the email, which is fine.  I think something is happening with the request in the Model... like a validation isn't being met.  Are you in Development mode?  Can you show :debug level errors to see what's happening?  Also, one more small thing, be sure to have this in config/environments/development.rb  

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }`

Or, whatever your host may be, this is a common pitfall.

Comment: I'm guessing you're running this in production, because I believe in "development" mode, the default is :debug.  If you don't know how you're running this, is it on your machine where you're developing it?  If so, you're probably in dev mode.  If not, whoever set up the app can tell you (it's probably "production" in that case).

If you open config/environments/production.rb  Look for this line:

`config.log_level = :info`

change to: `config.log_level = :debug`
and restart.

Comment: Ok so I changed that, and tried again. The log shows the following after the HTML for my confirmation email -   (8.7ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 976ms

SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
  app/models/confirmable.rb:75:in `send_confirmation_instructions'
  app/models/confirmable.rb:131:in `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions'

Comment: What Rails environment are you working in?  Production?  Can you edit your post and provide your config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb.  I'm looking for what you might have in your smtp_settings.  Reference:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: The SMTP settings are in the edit to my main question posted above. These are the production.rb settings

Comment: I set up a testMailer to send a test email. When I try from RAILS_ENV=development or RAILS_ENV=production console it returns nil.

Comment: Hard to tell from whatever MY_DOMAIN is, but if it really is running on the same server, you should check two things:  1) /etc/hosts includes "localhost" (without the double quotes) on the line with 127.0.0.1 and 2) that address: above also is equal to '127.0.0.1' or 'localhost' if '127.0.0.1' doesn't work.  Since you're getting this socket error, it appears it might be an error slightly outside your code and just what's available to your app.

Comment: this is what's in my hosts file    127.0.0.1       localhost domain

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: ok, did you change address in your smtp_settings to '127.0.0.1' or 'localhost' ?

Comment: I tried both. It then gave me Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):

Comment: From everything I've tried, it seems the process is just being blocked by my host. Is that possible or am I way off track? Because it says the email is being sent but then errors out after that. It is supposed to send the email and on successful send save the user and redirect but it never gets that far

Comment: I believe it says it is sending it, just before it attempts it.  This isn't clear to me, is the SMTP server on the same server as the production application?

Comment: The SMTP server is a GoDaddy hosting account, not on the same server as the app.

Comment: Ah, that changes things.  Your smtp_settings address should definitely be the exact SMTP FQDN at GoDaddy.  Also, you want to make sure you can connect to that SMTP server from your current server.

Comment: This might be the same, but definitely from *nix... follow this:  [http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html)  `telnet smtp.godaddy-whatever-their-smtp-url-is.com 25`  Make sure you are using the correct port number, they may not accept 25.

Comment: I did the telnet command, it said it connected and then after about 5 seconds it said Connection closed by foreign host.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to add another answer, but formatting here is important.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'MY_HOST' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
  :port                 => 80,
  :domain               => 'www.example.com',
  :user_name            => 'johndoe@example.com',
  :password             => 'yourpassword',
  :authentication       => 'plain'
}
end
```

**Notice I removed the starttls option, and set port to 80.  Obviously, replace with your real values.  If you're using constants, please avoid using those until this gets resolved.**